# Let anonymous users view certain analytics data via Google Appengine App (Python)

Tags: google-app-engine

I have made a simple script that retrieves a top 25 visited urls from our Google analytics account, and the data is outputted as I want it.

However I would like the output to be displayed eventhough the visitor hasn't logged in using a google account. Googling on the subject hasn't given me any pointers how to come about that task?

Comment: eh. probably easier to create your own view on to that information. in any case, as currently worded this isn't directly a programming question afaict. voting to close as off-topic. best of luck in your efforts

Comment: If you've written a script to retrieve the data, what's the problem? Just serve the results up without demanding authentication.

Answer (score 0):

do not configure login in your app.yaml

Comment: Specifically, don't require login for the URL that maps to the handler that will show your top 25 list.